# how to append a multi-line text after a formula in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I can make an automatically calcuated value appear a cell using '=' operator. For example, when cell `F20` is `200`,  I can enter in cell `G20`

```
=F20/10
```

Then, I see `20` in cell `G20`.

Now I want to add a note in cell `G20` so that it appears

```
20
note 4)
```

I know I can do

```
=concatenate(F20/10,"   note 4)")
```

but this obviously shows

```
20   note4)
```

which is not what I want.
How can I put `enter`(new line) in the appended text in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CHAR(10) which is newline:

```
=concatenate(F20/10,CHAR(10),"(note 4)")
```

Make sure you have 'Wrap Text' turned on for it to work.

Comment: I need to wait 4 more minutes to be able to choose it as an answer :) I don't know why SO made that rule.

Comment: By the way, when I use concatenate, the indentation is changed to stick to left cell boundary. Can I set the indent rule for concatenate? Of course I can set it at the 'format' menu.

Comment: Concatenate returns text. Defaults in Excel are text is left-aligned and numbers are right-aligned. You would be changing the rule for all text or all numbers, I'm assuming.

Comment: Hi, can you answer to my another question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529986/how-can-i-use-a-cell-formed-by-concatenation-of-a-number-and-a-text-as-input-to ?

Comment: Yes, I've answered that for you too. Thanks.